# How do I return each collection and its documents in firestore with cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Would like to return an array that has [1year, 1month, etc] and each of those are arrays that contain each document.

Currently, this returns an empty array but when I print the size of the snapshots I get the correct values. Not sure if i'm using push() correctly or if this is an async issue. Thanks.

[image: Here is an image of the database]

```
exports.getStockPrices = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const currentUser = {
      token: req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
    };
    // ! this is a post request
    admin
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(currentUser.token)
      .then(decodedToken => {
        // keep this just in case we want to add anything to do with the user
        const user = decodedToken;
        // array of collections e.g [1year, 1mo, etc]
        const data = [];
        // array of documents e.g [18948901, 1984010471, etc]
        const documents = [];
        db.collection('historical')
          .doc(`${req.body.ticker}`)
          .listCollections()
          .then(collections => {
            // each collection is the 1year, 1mo, etc
            collections.forEach(collection => {
              collection.get().then(querySnapshot => {
                console.log('number of documents: ' + querySnapshot.size);
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                  // doc.data is each piece of stock data
                  documents.push(doc.data());
                });
                // each document e.g 1year, 1mo, etc
                data.push(documents);
              });
            });
            return data;
          })
          .then(data => {
            return res.json({ data });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send({ error: 'error in getting data' });
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send({
          error: 'error authenticating user, please try logging in again'
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: You're not working with promises correctly.  You have to wait until after all the promises resolve before sending the final response.  You're sending an empty array because the response is being sent before the array populates.  You will see this if you add more console logging to see the order in which things happen.

Comment: @DougStevenson where are all the promises? I though my final .then() waits for them and then sends the final response. Thanks

Comment: Every `then` returns immediately with a promise.  It doesn't actually block the code.  If you add more debug logging you will see better what's going on.  You will have to learn in more detail how promises work.

Answer (score 0):

Due the nature of async calls, your return occurs before your array is being filled.

You can try my example, my firebase function is defined as `async` this allows me to use `await`, this statement allows to add a kind of sync for your firestore operations by waiting for the promises.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.eaxmple =  functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    var datax = []

    var collections = await db.collection('collection').doc('docid').listCollections()
    for (collection in collections) {
            content =  await collections[collection].get().then(querySnapshot => {
            console.log('number of documents: ' + querySnapshot.size);
            return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

        });
        datax.push(content)

    }
    return res.json({datax});


});
```